# How to write an integer in English words, in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

Do we have any jQuery method that takes an int value and returns the value in words?

Comment: [I made something like this in PHP like 40 years ago =) Maybe a little less. I considered it a game back then.](http://games.webblocks.nl/116) **edit** LOL @ the `html` 'code'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Working example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zq5rR/)

Here's a snippet that works from 1 to 999 that you might be able to modify to go higher, from http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3710:

```
var units = new Array ("Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen");
var tens = new Array ("Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety");

function num(it) {
    var theword = "";
    var started;
    if (it>999) return "Lots";
    if (it==0) return units[0];
    for (var i = 9; i >= 1; i--){
        if (it>=i*100) {
            theword += units[i];
            started = 1;
            theword += " hundred";
            if (it!=i*100) theword += " and ";
            it -= i*100;
            i=0;
        }
    };

    for (var i = 9; i >= 2; i--){
        if (it>=i*10) {
            theword += (started?tens[i-2].toLowerCase():tens[i-2]);
            started = 1;
            if (it!=i*10) theword += "-";
            it -= i*10;
            i=0
        }
    };

    for (var i=1; i < 20; i++) {
        if (it==i) {
            theword += (started?units[i].toLowerCase():units[i]);
        }
    };
    return theword;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can make your own.

Something like this may be a good place to start, although it has some bugs:

http://abhisanoujam.blogspot.com/2009/07/having-fun-with-jquery-numbers-to-words.html

Or this plain JavaScript version:

http://javascript.about.com/library/bltoword.htm

Comment: 1000 => "One Thousand Zero" Looks like it needs some debugging. ;-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Haha! Yes, I just found that and was updating my answer as you commented :)

Comment: `eightteen` should be `eighteen`.  Sorry to nit-pick :)

Comment: @afranz409: both the examples in my answer return `eighteen`.  Maybe let @Rudie know instead ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, there's nothing built into either JavaScript or jQuery that provides that feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try `jquery.num2words.js`

Source: https://github.com/faizalmansor/num2words