# Is there an easy way to convert an integer to its text equivalent. i.e: 1 becomes One

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an easy way in javascript/jquery to convert an int into its text equivalent?

So `var item = 1` becomes `item = "One"`..

Comment: Well, I mean you can hard code it but what if you have an item that can technically be infinite large there is no value in hard coding it...?

Comment: Have a look at the answers in the referred question, its not about *hardcoding*

Comment: This question looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904851/how-to-write-an-integer-in-english-words-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529934/javascript-numbers-to-words .

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
var a = ['','one ','two ','three ','four ', 'five ','six ','seven ','eight ','nine ','ten ','eleven ','twelve ','thirteen ','fourteen ','fifteen ','sixteen ','seventeen ','eighteen ','nineteen '];
var b = ['', '', 'twenty','thirty','forty','fifty', 'sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety'];

function inWords (num) {
    if ((num = num.toString()).length > 9) return 'overflow';
    n = ('000000000' + num).substr(-9).match(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{1})(\d{2})$/);
    if (!n) return; var str = '';
    str += (n[1] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[1])] || b[n[1][0]] + ' ' + a[n[1][1]]) + 'crore ' : '';
    str += (n[2] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[2])] || b[n[2][0]] + ' ' + a[n[2][1]]) + 'lakh ' : '';
    str += (n[3] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[3])] || b[n[3][0]] + ' ' + a[n[3][1]]) + 'thousand ' : '';
    str += (n[4] != 0) ? (a[Number(n[4])] || b[n[4][0]] + ' ' + a[n[4][1]]) + 'hundred ' : '';
    str += (n[5] != 0) ? ((str != '') ? 'and ' : '') + (a[Number(n[5])] || b[n[5][0]] + ' ' + a[n[5][1]]) + 'only ' : '';
    return str;
}
```

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766951/convert-digits-into-words-with-javascript)

Comment: Not really realistic... What if the number were 512 or 8020... Thanks though.

Comment: updated post,this work full